# How to use cin.get() instead of just cin?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to create a ceasar cipher, but when I type in my message, `cin` doesn't accept spaces, only the first word. My teacher told me to use `cin.get()` and not `cin.getline()`. How do I use `cin.get()` in this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  string message = "Empty";
  int opt = 0;
  int rotation = 0;
    extern char *optarg;
    static const char* opt_string = "r:f:h";
    opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);
    while(opt != -1)
    {
      switch (opt)
      {
      case 'r':
        rotation = atoi(optarg);
        cin >> message;
        for(int x = 0; x<message.length(); x++)
          message[x] = message[x] + rotation;
        cout << message << endl;
        break;
    }
    opt = getopt( argc, argv, opt_string);
  }


}
```

Comment: `char nextChar; if (std::cin.get(nextChar)) { /* process character */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation about cin.get: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

You should replace `cin >> message` with `cin.get (message,size_of_max_aprox_input)`